# Apple Watch App button in navigation bar

Tags: watchkit, apple-watch, navigationbar

I develop a Apple watch app using watch os 2.

Can I add button in "navigation bar" as this image :[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ESaTu.png).

[image]

In this image "Enzo" I would like to be a button.

Comment: :Have you got any solution for adding button on navigation bar in apple watch .I need same in my app.If yes then please help

Answer (score 0):

Nope—WatchKit apps don’t have the ability to add buttons to the navigation / status bar. If you’d like an API for that, you should [file an enhancement request](https://bugreport.apple.com).

Comment: Another solution to have an action from title? when i tap on title to have some action in interface controller. thx